# Duplicate magento contact form with separate post URL?

Tags: magento-1.7, forms, contact-us

I have duplicated magento contact form and implmented in My Account Section and its working fine, but when i submit the form its redirecting to contact us page.
How can i change the redirection url ?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the redirect for the contact form is in `app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php` -> `public function postAction()` -> `$this->_redirect('*/*/');` Successful redirect is the first one. You have to change `*/*/`.

Comment: Now it's redirecting to homepage, how can i redirect to same page ? and is it possible to customise the success message only for the duplicated form ?

Comment: You can try with `$this->_redirectReferer();`.

About the translation you can activate inline translate in the admin panel -> System -> Configuration -> ADVANCED -> Developer -> Translate Inline -> Enabled for Frontend : Yes.